# How to calculate current date and show it to each UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

my table view has 365 cells (number of days in year) now I need to show each date in each single cell for example if today is 2 Jul , the next cell should be 3 then 4 ,5 ,6 and ... .

```
     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return 365
    }


  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   // ... setup custom cell

   cell.day.text = dayIndexPath()
    return cell
}
```

now I am trying to create a method which gets current date :

```
  func dayIndexPath(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> String {

        let currentDate = NSDate()
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

        var convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
        convertedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(currentDate)

        let dayArray = [convertedDate]

        let row:Int = indexPath.row
        return  dayArray[row % dayArray.count]

}
```

The problem is above function only shows today date in each cells. I think I need to pass `currentDate` to `indexPath` and then calculate them to guess what is the next day. But I am not sure how to do so ! I would be grateful if you help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want to add a day by the next `indexPath.row` days, which will be 365 starting from today (indexPath.row = 0)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let todayDate = NSDate()
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
    let calculatedDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, value: indexPath.row, toDate: todayDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
    let calculatedDayString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(calculatedDate!)

    cell.textLabel?.text = calculatedDayString
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Greaaaat ! Thank you. What about this : lets assume 2 July is `234` from first day of year , how should I scroll the table view for example to 234th cell ? and continue date from there ?

Comment: @Mc.Lover if you're asking how to scroll to a specific cell programmatically there's a method called `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:` which achieves the goal. In this case you want to initialize the first date to be Jan 1st and not today's date.

Comment: @Mc.Lover: you can scroll tableview to 234th cell as follow: 
   `let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 234, inSection: 0)`
   `tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true) `

Answer (score 2):

Add this property at the top of your controller, because creation of date formatter is costly operation.

```
lazy var dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
    return dateFormatter
    }()
```

In table datesource method,

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

let todayDate = NSDate()
let finalDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Day, value: indexPath.row, toDate: todayDate, options: NSCalendarOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
if let finalDate = finalDate {
    cell.textLabel?.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(finalDate)
}

return cell
```

}